# Missing Push Notification Entitlement iOS App Submission (I don't use it)

Tags: ios, swift, itunes

I submitted a very basic app to the app store and I got this response:

> Missing Push Notification Entitlement - Your app appears to include
> API used to register with the Apple Push Notification service, but the
> app signature's entitlements do not include the "aps-environment"
> entitlement. If your app uses the Apple Push Notification service,
> make sure your App ID is enabled for Push Notification in the
> Provisioning Portal, and resubmit after signing your app with a
> Distribution provisioning profile that includes the "aps-environment"
> entitlement. See "Provisioning and Development" in the Local and Push
> Notification Programming Guide for more information. If your app does
> not use the Apple Push Notification service, no action is required.
> You may remove the API from future submissions to stop this warning.
> If you use a third-party framework, you may need to contact the
> developer for information on removing the API.

I have seen a lot of questions on here about this and how to ADD it, but I haven't seen anything (maybe I missed it) about if I don't even use it.  There's nothing in my app or when I submitted it mentioning push notifications.  The message says "no action is required" and that the submission was successful, and then I got an email soon after saying the app was submitted and was under review.

I just want to clarify that I really don't have to do anything?  It's my first submission and I don't want to assume I can just wait for approval/decline when this message they sent me is implying that I need to do something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that Apple has false positive.

If such is the case, this question has been answered here:

[How to remove push notification API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32127500/how-to-remove-push-notification-api/32128846#32128846)

If so, this question is a duplicate.