# Flutter iOS app submission issue warning: Missing Push Notification Entitlement

Tags: ios, flutter, apple-push-notifications, app-store

After uploading a Flutter app to App Store Connect, I got the following email warning:

> Dear Developer,
>
> We identified one or more issues with a recent delivery for your app,
>   "[APP NAME]". Your delivery was successful, but you may wish to correct
>   the following issues in your next delivery:
>
> **Missing Push Notification Entitlement** - Your app appears to register with the Apple Push Notification service, but the app
>   signature's entitlements do not include the "aps-environment"
>   entitlement. If your app uses the Apple Push Notification service,
>   make sure your App ID is enabled for Push Notification in the
>   Provisioning Portal, and resubmit after signing your app with a
>   Distribution provisioning profile that includes the "aps-environment"
>   entitlement. Xcode does not automatically copy the aps-environment
>   entitlement from provisioning profiles at build time. This behavior is
>   intentional. To use this entitlement, either enable Push Notifications
>   in the project editor's Capabilities pane, or manually add the
>   entitlement to your entitlements file. For more information, see
>   https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/HandlingRemoteNotifications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH6-SW1.
>
> After you’ve corrected the issues, you can use Xcode or Application
>   Loader to upload a new binary to App Store Connect.
>
> Best regards,
>
> The App Store Team

I don't use push notifications in my app? Why am I getting this warning? And how do I remove the "aps-environment" entitlement, wherever and whatever that is?

**Note:** This App Store issue has appeared multiple times on SO, sometimes because people needed to add push notifications (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14807129/missing-push-notification-entitlement) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27945557/missing-push-notification-entitlement-warning)) and sometimes because they didn't (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32261604/missing-push-notification-entitlement-ios-app-submission-i-dont-use-it) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32127500/how-to-remove-push-notification-api/32128846#32128846)). This appears to be Flutter related in my case, though, so I am adding a new question.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Word on the street is that as long as you really don't use push notifications this will not cause your app to get rejected. So you can safely (?) ignore this warning and continue to submit your app.

This issue is described on GitHub [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/9984). It's apparently somehow related to Flutter using the `UIApplicationDelegate` callback:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application
    didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary*)userInfo
          fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult result))completionHandler;
```

I'll let someone else explain the exact reason more clearly. Keep an eye on the GitHub issue.

For now I am just going to ignore the warning.

**Update:** I submitted my app, it was accepted, and there hasn't been any problem with it since then. So just ignore the warning.

Comment: Now, this issue should be resolved. Update your Flutter version https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/9984

Comment: I just updated flutter, and still got this issue @VinceVarga, any ideas?   from Flutter doctor: Channel stable, v1.5.4-hotfix.2, on Mac OS X 10.14.5 18F132, locale en-US

Comment: Try selecting a different channel, the fix was merged like two weeks ago. Stable got released less often than that (see https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Flutter-build-release-channels). I'm on `dev` and I don't receive the complaining mails from Apple anymore `Flutter 1.7.3 • channel dev`

Comment: Update, it's probably not fixed yet. For latest status, see: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/9984#issuecomment-505602616

Comment: This issue still exists in v1.12.13+hotfix.8

Comment: Looks like the issue still exists in 1.17.3... Just received the same email...

Comment: What about someone who *IS* using notifications?

Comment: @MuhammadbinYusrat, in that case you do need to register your app for push notifications. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/registering_your_app_with_apns

Comment: I came across the same email while uploading a Flutter app to App Store Connect. Just one quick question. Do i need to implement this function and upload a new binary? or my previous binary will do just fine? This statement **you may wish to correct the following issues in your next delivery** is confusing me.

Comment: @NaveedUlHassan5, For me I just used the previous binary.

Comment: It's now in 9984 https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/9984

Comment: I created an app today - December 2th 2021 - and submitted it, it does not use push notifications and STILL got the scary email.

Comment: It still exists in 2.2.whatever and up. It's actually turned into a HUGE issue for me because the client for which I'm writing this app doesn't want the error when they push the code to their App Store uploads. (sigh) My god, I continue to hate flutter.

Comment: Still happening on flutter 3.7.12 :/

Comment: Not only is it still a bug, Apple DID reject our app as of Dec 2023. It's removed from the store until we setup the push entitlement. We aren't using push. So this is now critical.

Answer (score 23):

As of today this problem is still not fixed in Flutter.
See the [Issue 9984](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/9984).

While this should not cause any rejects in the App Store it still needs to be fixed and there seems to be a workaround for this (also [described](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/9984#issuecomment-528649926) in the issue above):

Add a file **Runner.entitlements** under ios/Runner/Runner.entitlements with this content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>aps-environment</key>
    <string>development</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: This means that you are also asking for permission to send push notifications without actually sending push notifications, doesn't it?

Comment: @Suragch basically yes. It sets the push notification environment to development. If you are using XCode it will be set automatically. See also [aps-environment](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/entitlements/aps-environment)

Comment: I had this added a few months ago and the error disappeared. However, today the warning appeared again. Should I remove this file or is there any other underlying issue related to the entitlements?

Comment: I agree, in addition you still need to go to Signing & Capabilities and add "Push Notifications" from "+ Capability"

Comment: @Suragch adding this makes the warning disappear, and it DOES NOT ask the user  for permission, so it seems like a good solution without side effects.

Answer (score 13):

My app does use push notifications so I wanted to make sure this was working. I found this post very helpful: [Flutter/App Store Connect Warning: ITMS-90078 Missing Push Notification Entitlement](https://www.ernestchiang.com/en/posts/2020/flutter-itms-90078-missing-push-notification-entitlement/)

Open the Flutter project (Runner) in XCode.
Under Signing & Capabilities, press '+Capability' and scroll down to find Push Notifications.
XCode will generate the “ios/Runner/Runner.entitlements” file.
Done. My build appeared on next attempt.

Comment: Interesting @chrisfavritz  Just had the same issue. Does this mean, that we let Apple know that we want to use push notifications? I am actually not using push notifications for anything and basically does not need this at all.

Answer (score 7):

Our app does not use the push notification function but Flutter is using the UIApplicationDelegate callback (source). The App Store Connect does not reject our app distribution (as long as we are not actually using push notifications). It is a warning message. Some may just ignore this warning.

**Solution:**

If you want to (kind of) resolve this warning, here is a workaround:

1. Open the Flutter project (Runner) in XCode.
2. Enable "Push Notifications" under Capabilities. (refer to the screenshot below)
3. XCode will generate the “ios/Runner/Runner.entitlements” file.
4. Done

[image]

**Reference**

- Content of “ios/Runner/Runner.entitlements” file (generated by XCode):

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>aps-environment</key>
    <string>development</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```