# Flutter iOS push not being received

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I have an issue with push notifications not being received on an iOS device in my Flutter app.

I tried to follow this guide: https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/apple-integration/

Steps I have made to configure my push notifications:

1. Register my APN from developer.apple.com on Firebase Console (Cloud Messaging -> my app)
2. Used the GoogleServices-Info.plist from firebase
3. Built the app and uploaded to TestFlight
4. Asked the user for permission to show notifications on iOS
5. Copied the fcm token from my app and pasted it into Firebase Console -> Cloud Messaging -> new campaign
6. Push has not been received by my physical iPhone that has the app installed from TestFlight.

I also have made sure I have XCode configured properly and:

1. I have selected Push Notifications and Background Modes (Background fetch, Remote notifications)
   [image]
2. I am using the proper bundle identifier (lol)
3. My App ID has Push Notifications selected
   [image]
4. My APN key has the Push Notifications Service selected
   [image]

Any idea on what I am doing wrong? Anyone experienced a similar issue?

EDIT:
This is my `AppDelegate.swift` file, maybe it's somewhat helpful in resolving my issue (worth mentioning - I didn't touch it, it's generated by flutter I guess):

```swift
import UIKit
import Flutter
import FirebaseMessaging

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
    
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }
    
    override func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {

       Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken
       super.application(application, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken: deviceToken)
     }
}
```

Also have received such an email from Apple when submitted a build to Test Flight:
[image]

EDIT:
I have checked my `.entitlements` file and it says `production`. I also checked the `Payload/AppName.app/embedded.mobileprovision` and it also says `production`.

I also have added the APNs certificate in Firebase Messaging:
[image]

I connected my iPhone 8 to my MacBook and opened the console app for my iPhone 8. I found out, that when I launch my app, the console says:

`No valid 'aps-environment' entitlement string found for application 'pl.mycompany.myproject.myapp': (null).`

I suspect, it could be related to me signing, building and uploading the app using Fastlane, since I do have my `aps-environment` set to `development` when uploading in my `myapp/ios/Runner/Runner.entitlements`

I also get those prints in the console:

`[pl.mycompany.myproject.myapp] Push registration with a nil environment was encountered, will not invalidate token`

`[pl.mycompany.myproject.myapp] Ignore becoming foreground for application without push registration`

Comment: please check this, maybe it will help you.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/55167613/12187270

Comment: The problem in the thread you linked was that the person uploading the build didn't actually use push notifications in their app. I am trying to receive them, but fail to do so.

Comment: Did you solve the issue @davdog00 ? I have a very similar issue at the moment

Comment: @imtoori - I did not solve the issue in a standard way. What I did is I created a completely new project and configured all firebase services using flutterfire_cli, used xcodes automatic signing and not used fastlane sigh or cert this time.

Answer (score 3):

The **ITMS-90078** issue you're getting from the App Store indicates that the final app signature's entitlements is missing the `aps-environment` entry. Thus, Push Notifications may not work as expected with TestFlight builds.

First, make sure that *all* of the `.entitlements` files in your Xcode project do contain the said entry with the appropriate value (usually `development` or `production`).

Secondly, on the machine used to build the app, make sure that the local copy of the provisioning profile at `~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles` does contain the `aps-environment` entry. If it does not, you should download the provisioning profile again and replace your local copy.

Ultimately, to verify that the final provisioning profile does contain the `aps-environment` value, you could unzip the built IPA and navigate to `Payload/AppName.app/embedded.mobileprovision`. You may check that the *Entitlements* section actually contains that key with the expected value.

If not, your entitlement file(s) or provisioning profiles could be altered by one of the build phases (which is a lot less likely).

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, I have checked my .entitlements file and it says `production`. I also checked the `Payload/AppName.app/embedded.mobileprovision` and it also says `production`.

Comment: Can you confirm that you downloaded the newly created provisioning profile after you enabled Push Notifications for your App ID on *developer.apple.com* ? Xcode may still use an old version of the profile. To make sure, you may delete your app's provisioning profile at `~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles`, and then disable and re-enable Xcode's automatic signing. It will download the latest version of the profile, which may fix your issue.

Comment: Each time I build the `.ipa` for upload, I sign the app using a profile downloaded by fastlane (generated by the command `fastlane run update_code_signing_settings use_automatic_signing:false path:ios/Runner.xcodeproj`. I have also tried to use Xcodes automatic signing (which also didn't help). Is there a way to check if the provisioning profile file has specific services enabled? Also, worth mentioning, the push notifications for my App ID on _developer.apple.com_ has been enabled a long time ago.

Comment: I also have tried launching my app with a console attached to my phone. When opening the app, I get this console message:
[pl.my.app.bundleId] Ignore becoming foreground for application without push registration

Comment: Since you are using Fastlane, is the binary directly uploaded from your pipeline ? Or do you use a tool such as Transporter to upload it ? Obviously, some step in the process is altering or improperly generating the binary's signature — otherwise the App Store would not emit this warning.

Comment: Yes, I use transporter to upload the binary. More specificallly, fastlane does: `fastlane deliver --ipa <IPA_PATH> --username <MY_EMAIL> --submission_information {\"export_compliance_uses_encryption\": false} --skip_metadata --skip_screenshots --team_id <MY_TEAM_ID> --api_key_path ios_upload_cert.json --precheck_include_in_app_purchases false`

I need to mention, that I also tried to switch back to automatic code signing (with xcode), this is when I also didn't manage to make the push notifications to be dellivered. That time I also uploaded the binary via Xcode -> Archive

Answer (score 0):

Basing from experience
I'm assuming the push notification is working when in debug mode right?

Funnily enough in my case the APNS Cert was only for development double check your apns certificate that might be the culprit!! :)

or might as well remake the certs ~

Comment: I am not able to test push notifications in debug mode, right? I haven't seen a push notification on iOS in this app for half a year now... :(

Answer (score 0):

1. Did you add certificate in firebase project? [image: List item]

2. Use Flutter you don't need to import FirebaseMessigng in AppDelegate.
- Just `import Firebase` then call `FirebaseApp.configure()` in `application` func.
- If you configure firebase and newest documents use firebase cli instead of GoogleServices-Info.plist you even don't need modify your AppDelegate
https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/cli/

3. Did you call `await Firebase.initializeApp();` after call `WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();` and before build your app?
4. I think you should try local script to push notification to ensure
   your configuration is right.
   `xcrun simctl push simulator-device-id app-bundle-id notification.apns`
   with *notification.apns* is file contains payload test, for example:

`{ "aps": { "alert": "APNs demo", "sound": "default", "badge": 69 } }`

https://sarunw.com/posts/testing-remote-push-notification-in-ios-simulator/

Answer (score -2):

Delete your key in your developer account, and create another one, and upload it again on your firebase. That will solve your problem.